# Intel SIMD Intrinsics: _mm256_i64scatter_pd

Tags: simd, avx2

I'm having trouble compiling Intel SIMD scatter intrinsics.  I've simplified my original code to this:

```
double *tmpMemoryDoubles= (double *) malloc(1024);
__m256i tmpRegisterIndex = _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 1, 2, 3);
__m256d tmpRegisterDouble = _mm256_set_pd(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
_mm256_i64scatter_pd(tmpMemoryDoubles, tmpRegisterIndex, tmpRegisterDouble, 1);
```

The documentation for _mm256_i64scatter_pd() defines the parameters as:

```
void   _mm256_i64scatter_pd (void* base_addr, __m256i vindex, __m256d a, const int scale)
```

This is the error message:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/avx512vlintrin.h:11152:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline 'void _mm256_i64scatter_pd(void*, __m256i, __m256d, int)': target specific option mismatch
_mm256_i64scatter_pd (void *__addr, __m256i __index,
src_avx2/PRE_build_region_impulse_devel_avx2.cpp:631:33: note: called from here
_mm256_i64scatter_pd(tmpMemoryDoubles, tmpRegisterIndex, tmpRegisterDouble, 1);
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could this possibly stem from me not having a AVX512 CPU?

Comment: I guess I would have expected a more informative error message if the AVX512 issue was the cause.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an AVX2 instruction.  If you compiled with `-march=native` and the compiler gave you this, your CPU doesn't have AVX512VL.  AVX2 only has gathers; scatters are new with AVX512.

GCC and clang require ISA extensions to be enabled for them to emit those instructions, even if you use intrinsics.  (Unlike MSVC and ICC).  You could compile with `-mavx512vl` or `-march=skylake-avx512` to compile successfully, and then fault at runtime on CPUs that don't support it.

That's what `target specific option mismatch` means; if you'd googled on `inlining failed in call to always_inline` and/or `target specific option mismatch`, you would have found lots of hits about needing `-mwhatever`.

Or if you'd looked up `_mm256_i64scatter_pd` in [Intel's intrinsics finder](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/), you'd see that it requires AVX512VL.